# JQuery send JSON to Spring MVC controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring, model-view-controller

I' not able to send a JSON object with JQuery Ajax to a Spring MVC controller. This is the definition of the method of my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "InboxViewTemplate")
public class InboxViewController {

@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "updateInboxView")
    public String updateInboxView(HttpServletRequest request, InboxView inboxView) {
...
}
```

then I'm trying to invoke this request:

```
$.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: ctx + "/InboxViewTemplate/updateInboxView",
            data: ({inboxView : {createUser:"dave"}}),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#updateInboxView").html(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqXHR + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
            }
          });
      }
```

but the JSON object is not passed. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

First of all your controller doesn't know where to look for InboxView. Is it a request parameter? Path param? Request body?

Second of all you probably want to change your json request type to POST or PUT as you're updating data not just retrieving it.

So something like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "InboxViewTemplate")
public class InboxViewController {

@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "updateInboxView", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateInboxView(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody InboxView inboxView) {
    ...
}
```

and

```
$.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: ctx + "/InboxViewTemplate/updateInboxView",
            type: 'POST',
            data:  JSON.stringify({inboxView : {createUser:"dave"}}), //if no JSON is available use the one from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js
            success: function(data) {
                $("#updateInboxView").html(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqXHR + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
            }
          });
      }
```

should work.

I'm assuming here that you have your json message converter configured properly.

**edit**
Meaning that you have:

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
<property name="messageConverters">
  <list>
    <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
  </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

or something equivalent for other message converters in your spring xml config.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, now I get a 404 error. I have also tried with  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"createUser":"John"}'); and passing this object to the mvc method. Seems that does not recognize the RequestBody object. Others configuration should I try ? Or is incorrect my ajax request ? Many thanks.

Comment: @carlo first check if you can connect to your controller (using curl or telnet). Then check if you have any errors in your server log. Check if you have  <context:annotation-config/> in your spring context. And lastly check if your message converter is configured properly. See my edit.

Comment: Now happens a think that I'm not able to understand: if I remove the annotation @RequestBody, the services is invoked instead if is present the annotation I have a 404 error. How debug this situation ? Thank you.

Comment: @carlo hmm, make sure you changed the request type of your jquery to 'post'. otherwise jquery will try to encode the json in url and i think spring doesn't yet know how to deal with it.

Comment: yes, the type of request is this: $.ajax({
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json",
   url: ctx + "/InboxViewTemplate/updateInboxView",
   type: "POST",
   cache : false,
   data : { name : "appId"},
   success: function(data) {
    $("#updateInboxView").html(data);
   },
   error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(jqXHR + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
   }
    });

Comment: @carlo post, if you can your web.xml, application context, jsp and InboxView + InboxViewController classes. It's hard to diagnose the problem without looking at some more code.

Comment: @carlo i just noticed that the answer was missing JSON serialization on jquery part. A bit of a late call, i know :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen your log file to find out the reason of 404. I suspect you need the jakson related jar file to put in your lib.